# should i create splash screen in xamarin forms?

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms

how to create splash screen using xamarin.forms.

splash screen does show up but no image

SplashActivity

```
[Activity(Label = "SplashActivity",
        Theme = "@style/SplashTheme",
        MainLauncher = true,
        NoHistory = true)]
    public class SplashActivity : Activity
    {
        protected override void OnCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
        {
            base.OnCreate(savedInstanceState);

            // Create your application here
        }
    }
```

style.xml

```
  <style name="SplashTheme" parent="android:Theme">
      <item name="android:windowBackground">@drawable/splashscreen</item>
      <item name="android:windowNoTitle">true</item>
      <item name="android:windowFullscreen">true</item>
  </style>
```

Comment: Can you share your `@drawable/splashscreen`?

Comment: yeah its just a png image in drawable folder (android project)

Answer (score 0):

just took a step back, and found a solution. I am using shared xamarin.forms, why not just create 1st xamarin page into splash screen.

there is no point in creating acivities/xml/drawable just to set up a splashscreen into android project, than set up again in to ios project, than set up again in windows project....

this fixed it for me and it works in anroid, ios and windows

create a splashscreen view page with just a image

```
               <Image x:Name="ssImage" Source="splashscreen.png"
                VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand" 
                HorizontalOptions="CenterAndExpand"
                HeightRequest="500"
                WidthRequest="500" />
```

backend just send build animation function

```
public SplashscreenPage ()
    {
        InitializeComponent ();

        Animation();
    }

    public async void Animation()
    {
        ssImage.Opacity = 0;
        
        await Task.WhenAll(
            ssImage.FadeTo(100, 3000),
            ssImage.ScaleTo(1.3, 3000)
            );

        Application.Current.MainPage = new CreatePinPage();
    }
```